# Matplotlib working on one CSV but not a near identical one

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, typeerror

I have written a short python program that checks and logs internet upspeed and downspeed, I am now trying to write another program that plots that data from a CSV.

The issue that I'm having is that I thought I was done and went to test it one one CSV and it worked perfectly! but I went to test it with the CSV generated from today's report and I only get a string of errors. I can't figure it out because the two CSVs were made by the same logging program and are completely identical other than the time and speed data.

I'm fairly new to python and it's likely that I am missing something extremely simple but I just cannot seem to figure out what is happening or why they would be different so any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is also my first time asking a question here so apologies if my post is formatted poorly.

Plotting program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

column1 = ["date","time","downspeed","upspeed"]

df1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=column1)

y = df1.downspeed
x = df1.time
z = df1.upspeed
date_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a %d/%m/%y")

df1["Time period"] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df1["Downspeed"] = df1.downspeed
df1["Upspeed"] = df1.upspeed

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.set(xlabel="Time",
       ylabel="Speed",
       title="Internet Speed Graph ("+str(date_now)+")")

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20, 10]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
  

plt.plot(x,y,label = "downspeed", linewidth=2, color='m')
plt.plot(x,z,label = "upspeed", linewidth=2, color='c')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

CSV that works perfectly:

```
date,time,downspeed,upspeed
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:21,169.76,61
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:22,164.51,83.07
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:23,160.9,75.27
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:25,162.4,70.5
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:26,170.17,78.98
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:27,164.52,84.12
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:29,161.87,75.31
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:30,156.45,65.29
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:31,160.17,70.88
,,,
Fri 02/12,12:33,170.32,85.78
```

[Output of working CSV plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gsv2.png)

CSV that refuses to plot and throws errors:

```
date,time,downspeed,upspeed
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:00,47.81,15.3
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:01,45.41,15.49
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:03,49.5,15.55
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:04,50.31,15.77
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:05,49.92,15.83
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:07,44.93,15.52
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:08,49.69,14.75
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:09,48.89,15.37
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:11,43.81,14.78
,,,
Sat 03/12,0:12,48.74,15.11
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\calla>python "Plotter_with_date.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Plotter_with_date.py", line 34, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,y,label = "downspeed", linewidth=2, color='m')
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2740, in plot
    return gca().plot(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1662, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 311, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 499, in _plot_args
    self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1608, in update_units
    default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 116, in default_units
    axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.update(data)
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 227, in update
    _api.check_isinstance((str, bytes), value=val)
  File "C:\Users\calla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py", line 93, in check_isinstance
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), that goes for the csv files too, the issue might be non printng chars which we can't see on an image.

Comment: @cafce25 Apologies, I have now put all of this data into code blocks instead

Comment: I get the same error for both csv files, are you certain you copied them and the code and they are the same as the one you're running? There seem to be extraneous lines of `,,,` in between the lines of data.

Comment: They're definitely the exact same. It may be because to put the CSV data on this post I ran the type command on the file and copied the output, I couldn't find a better way to do it since SO doesn't do attachments.

Comment: Well with the `,,,` lines removed your script works on the csv data, with them in it it fauils with your error for both files.

Comment: the ,,, lines are the command line's interpretations of a blank row. I've just edited my logging program to not print blank lines between every row so that won't happen with future logs. But that's more of a preference thing since matplotlib didn't seem to care about blank rows.